# CSS position relative not repected by Firefox print

Tags: html, css, printing, margin

I need to chain a series of div containers (position:relative) to print full page.  Each container contains different divs (position:absolute).  On the screen FF does a good job but when I print, the first page divs inside the container are well placed but after that they are not.  Is that a bug or something that can be corrected in my code?

Safari respects the absolute position on page>1 but does not set the margin to 0.  How can I do that?

I have not tested in chrome yet... since I had big issue with it;)

So what is the solution that works for all major browsers?  margin=0 absolute on pages>1...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <style>
 @page { margin: 0cm !important; }
 html, body, div, p, li { margin:0; font-family:Calibri; color:#858484; }
 .container1 { position:relative; background-image:url('bgn1.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:210mm; height:297mm; padding:0; }
 .container1 { page-break-after: always }
 .container2 { position:relative; background-image:url('bgn2.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; width:210mm; height:297mm; padding:0; }
 .container2 { page-break-after: always }
 html, body, div, p, li { margin:0; font-family:Calibri; color:#858484; }
 .div-logos { background-image:url('logos.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; }
 .div-logos { position:absolute; top:200mm; left:48mm; width:150mm; height:14mm; padding:0; }
 .div-logos { border:1px solid blue; }</style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container1">
     <div class="div-logos"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="container2">
     <div class="div-logos"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```